If an object is highly stiff, does that indicate that it is highly elastic?

Does stifness imply elasticity

Are all objects that are stiff elastic and examples



Did you at least try to do some minimal reading about it? e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness#Relationship_to_elasticity
